# Como hago para que la regex ignore los tags y solo tome como valido que empieze y termine como lo indica

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, regex, condiciones

```py
import re, random, os
from unicodedata import normalize

def additional_precoded_phrases(input_text, text):

    #Quita acentos y demas diacríticos excepto la ñ
    input_text = re.sub(
        r"([^n\u0300-\u036f]|n(?!\u0303(?![\u0300-\u036f])))[\u0300-\u036f]+", r"\1",
        normalize("NFD", input_text), 0, re.I
    )

    input_text = normalize( 'NFC', input_text) # -> NFC
```

Asi empieza y hasta ahi todo bien pero el tema es que no se bien como plantear las siguientes condiciones con las *regex*

Quiero que empieze asi, pero si hay tags `#<@! el alfanumerico_de_tag >`  delante o detras que los ignore y tome como positiva la condicion planteada en el if

```py
    patron_directo_n = r"^(?:estoy bien|estoy|estoy bien!|ya estoy|estaba|ya estaba|ya estaba eso|ya estaba esto|ya estaba esta)$"
    #n = re.search(patron_directo_n, input_text, re.IGNORECASE) #recorre todo el string en busca de la coincidencia
    n = re.match(patron_directo_n, input_text, re.IGNORECASE) #evalua el string desde el inicio

    if n:
        answer_num = random.randint(1, 3)

        if answer_num == 1:
            text = "Oh ya veo"
        elif answer_num == 2:
            text = "Oh eso veo"
        elif answer_num == 3:
            text = "Ohh eso parece"

    else:
        pass
```

Ejemplos:

- `#<@! el alfanumerico_de_tag > hola` ---> que lo tome como False
- `#<@! el alfanumerico_de_tag > estoy bien` ---> que lo tome como True
- `#<@! el alfanumerico_de_tag >estoy bien` ---> que lo tome como True
- `#<@! el alfanumerico_de_tag > Yo fui a caminar al parque, y ahora estoy bien` ---> que lo tome como False
- `#<@! el alfanumerico_de_tag > estoy bien, y tu como te encuentras?`  ---> que lo tome como False
- `Hola estoy bien`  ---> que lo tome como False
- `estoy bien`  ---> que lo tome como True

---

```py
import re

#testing = ["#<@!0090dalaw> hola","#<@!0090dalaw> estoy bien","#<@!0090dalaw>estoy bien","#<@!0090dalaw> Yo fui a caminar al parque, y ahora estoy bien","estoy bien"]
testing = ["estoy bien<@!808947310809317386> ", "estoy bien por aqui "]

#regex para validar patron
regex = re.compile("^(<@!.+>){,1}\s{,}(estoy bien|estoy|estoy bien!|ya estoy|estaba|ya estaba|ya estaba eso|ya estaba esto|ya estaba esta)(<@!.+>){,1}\s{,}$")
#regex para validar tag
regex_tag = re.compile("^<@!.+>") 

#probamos
for test in testing:
    if regex.match(test):
        not_tag = " ".join(regex_tag.split(test))
        print(not_tag)
```

Ante esto toma como True solo la primera string de la cadena, pero no quita el tag del final

´estoy bien<@!808947310809317386>´

Pero almenos de este modo la oracion

´estoy bien por aqui´  la toma correctamente como False

Solo queda quitar los tags si aparecen detras, lo cual parece complicado por la manera en la cual cortarlos en esos casos

Comment: No habías hecho una pregunta similar?

Comment: Si al final habia encontrado una solucion pero que no era tan efectiva, luego por temas de estudio deje ahi por unos dias, y estube investigando aun asi no logro limitar el uso de tags para que tome verdad si esta o no los tags

Comment: No estoy segura que combinacion de regex usar para eso, porque hacer que lo tome textual es facil pero hacer que si hay algo delante que no sea un tag entonces sea False eso es dificil, porque si lo que esta adelante es un tag entonces seguiria siendo True

Comment: la verdad se me esta complicando hacer que se cumplan todas las condiciones juntas, osea que quite el tag y ahi analice si es identica o no, pero debe haber un modo de quitar o ignorar el tag porque ese tag puede estar delante o detras

Comment: los metacaracteres te pueden ayudar, como por ejemplo `^` o `$`, tal vez haga una respuesta

Comment: con esos para establecer inicio y fin estube probando pero da problemas, claro a menos que lo combines con algo mas, a mi se me estubo complicando meter todo junto. Lo que se me habia ocurrido es buscar un modo de quitar todos los tags sin importar donde esta y luego de ahi analizar si coincide completo(osea textual) o no

Comment: Creo que mejor sería al revés, te voy a dar una respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estoy seguro si se pueda hacer con una sola expresión regular, para este caso te propongo hacerlo con 2, una para detectar el patrón y otra para quitar el tag.

Para esto cree un *sistema de pruebas* donde puse todos los ejemplos que das en una lista para luego recorrerlas y validarlas.

```py
import re

testing = ["#<@!0090dalaw> hola","#<@!0090dalaw> estoy bien","#<@!0090dalaw>estoy bien","#<@!0090dalaw> Yo fui a caminar al parque, y ahora estoy bien","estoy bien"]

#regex para validar patron
regex = re.compile("^(#<@!.+>){,1}\s{,}(estoy bien|estoy|estoy bien!|ya estoy|estaba|ya estaba|ya estaba eso|ya estaba esto|ya estaba esta)")
#regex para validar tag
regex_tag = re.compile("^#<@!.+>") 

#probamos
for test in testing:
    if regex.match(test):
        not_tag = " ".join(regex_tag.split(test))
        print(not_tag)
```

**resultado**

```
estoy bien #segundo ejemplo
estoy bien #tercer ejemplo
estoy bien #ultimo ejemplo
```

La primera regex dice: la cadena debe contener `<!@ cualquier cosa>` ninguna o una vez luego debe ir seguido por ningún o varios espacios y luego debe de tener `(serie de palabras)`.
Primero valido si la cadena contiene el patrón deseado (el de `<tag> palabra_valida`) y en caso lo tenga luego hago la separación. Lo haga asi para no hacer un `split` de todas las cadenas donde solo algunas van a cumplir, mejor verifico cuales cumplen y si cumplen hago la separación, de esta forma no hago operaciones de mas.

Comment: Muchas gracias probe de otro modo basado en el tuyo y agarra el unico tema es cortar si el tag se da al final de la oracion

Comment: En ese caso solo quitarle el `^` a `regex_tag`